# Download Mediatailor m3u8 stream as MP4 with midroll ads

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-mediatailor

We have setup mediatailor m3u8 stream that has midroll ads. If that stream was downloaded as MP4 will it include those midroll ads?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. The short answer is yes because the ad segments are listed in the playback manifest produced by MediaTailor just as the program segments are.